# Creating pie of pie chart amCharts

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

#### Introduction:

Recently I have started to work with `amCharts v4`. I studied the documentation, however I did not find the required informations. I have a specific usecase, where I need to create a **pie of pie chart**. So I started to wonder ...

> Has `amCharts` possibility to create pie of pie chart? Is there any other free JS library, which is available to do that?

*Any tips would be higly appreciated. Thanks in advance.*

#### What I am trying to construct:

[image: Pie of pie]
Pie of pie chart - image taken from [link](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/bootstrap/chart/pieofpie)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating two pie charts next to each other is really easy with amCharts - you simply create a container, set it's layout to "horizontal" and then add two pie charts to it. Drawing lines like in the demo requires some geometry and amCharts layout knowledge, so I made this demo (try clicking on slices) to illustrate it:

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/pie-of-a-pie/

Comment: A million thanks sir, a little tweaking and it works according to my thoughts. I would hardly make it, really appreciate the demo, thanks.